# Visual studio Express 2013 for the Web Controls greyed in the toolbox

Tags: visual-studio

I have `VS2013 Express` for the Web installed and it works fine, but today I wanted to test something for WebForm. I try different type of project, `new Project` or `new WebSite` but in any case in Design View of any pages the controls in the toolbox are greyed and disabled. Onlyt the Html components are enabled.
I didn't find any solution up to now.

Comment: What type of project are you using?

Comment: I tryed WebForm Application in Web/Visual Studio 2012 , New Project/Asp.net Web Application and WebForm Choice or even New Web SIte . All give the same trouble